# Executing a method in parent user control from a child in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user control named `Display` in  `MainWindow.xaml`. `Display` user control itself has a custom class `Workspace.cs` in it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Program.Main.Controls.Display.Display"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:workspaces="clr-namespace:Program.Workspaces">

    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <workspaces:Workspace x:Name="MyWorkspace" ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

In my custom class that is `Worskspace.cs` I'm rising a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, I want to execute the `ThisCommandCameFromWorkspace` method in `Display.xaml.cs` when rising this event.

What is the best approach to do this? And What is the easiest?

**Updated:**

In my Workspace.cs I have

```
public event Action MyEventHandler;

private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            if (MyEventHandler!= null)
                MyEventHandler();
    }
```

Now I want to capture this in `Display` user control and execute a method of its code-behind.

Comment: [*Routed Events Overview*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Bubble an event up - don't try and reach into the parent to execute anything directly.

Comment: @slugster Thanks, what if I had different classes inside the `Display` user control which all may raise a `MouseButtonLeftDown` event depending on which one is active at the time, when the event bubbles up and the parent element captures it, how will it know that which child class sent it?

Comment: Are you programatically raising the event (by RaiseEvent)? Why not define explicit events of the inner control and let the outer attach a handler?

Comment: @Clemens No, I'm doing it as in the updated part, I have raised events like this before user controls and subscribed to them in my `MainWindow` but for this I'm having problems.

Comment: What problems? It should work that way.

Comment: @Clemens How can I subscribe to this in `Display.xaml` or `Display.xaml.cs`? The `MyEventHandler` is not recognized in `Display.xaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not to use `Action` as event delegate type, but instead use the common type `EventHandler`. And don't call it `MyEventHandler` as it is not a handler, but just the event:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyEvent != null)
    {
        MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now you would easily attach a handler for the event in the Display's XAML (supported by Intellisense in Visual Studio):

```
<workspaces:Workspace ... MyEvent="Display_MyEvent"/>
```

Comment: It is very odd :( I just created a sample program and it is working. I don't know why it is not working in my main program.

Comment: Thank you so much Clemens, I just got it working. It is odd because  I was doing the same things before! It seems things just start to work when you show up. Thanks.